# WiX: Installing to Multiple DB Targets

Tags: database, wix, installation

I have a set of DB scripts that I need to run during install.  I have a UI screen that the user can select the server, provide credentials, and then select the target database.  What I need to do is install the bulk of the scripts to the target database the user selected but some scripts need to go to the Master DB.  I've tried searching the net for answers but I haven't really found anything that tells me how to do that.  If someone has an article or suggestion on how this is accomplished, I would appreciate a little help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare two SqlDatabase nodes, one for each database where the scripts have to be run:

```
<Binary Id="SqlScriptBinary1" SourceFile="script1.sql" />
<Binary Id="SqlScriptBinary2" SourceFile="script2.sql" />

  <Component Id='SqlComponent.Sql1' Guid='YOUR-GUID-HERE' KeyPath='yes'>
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id='Database1' Database='[DATABASE_NAME1]' Server='[DATABASE_SERVER]' 
                     CreateOnInstall='no' 
                     DropOnInstall='no' DropOnReinstall='no' DropOnUninstall='no' 
                     ContinueOnError='no'>
      <sql:SqlScript Id='SqlScript1' BinaryKey='SqlScriptBinary1' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
    </sql:SqlDatabase>
  </Component>

  <Component Id='SqlComponent.Sql2' Guid='YOUR-GUID-HERE' KeyPath='yes'>
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id='Database2' Database='[DATABASE_NAME2]' Server='[DATABASE_SERVER]' CreateOnInstall='no' 
                     DropOnUninstall='no' DropOnInstall='no' DropOnReinstall='no' ContinueOnError='no'>
      <sql:SqlScript Id='SqlScript2' BinaryKey='SqlScriptBinary2' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
    </sql:SqlDatabase>
  </Component>
```

Do a quick search and you'll find articles that may help you, such as [this one](http://www.rareese.com/blog/using-wix-to-install-sql-databases-and-execute-sql-scripts) for example.

Comment: Thanks.  I've book marked the article you provided.  I've been searching for this answer and was unable to find one.  Thus my question here.  I shall use your suggestion and see if I can make that work.